# Python Pandas strip letters out after center indicator "|"

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for an efficient way to remove all characters after first"|"

Data looks like:

```
    category      qty
1    abc|xyz       23
2    dfs|oif       43
3    fds|fd|a      34
4    qwe|lf        34
5    fds|fa|fds    21
```

I need to trim these data to:

```
     category      qty
1    abc           23
2    dfs           43
3    fds           34
4    qwe           34
5    fds           21
```

I tried `.str.lstrip('|')` but got an error:

> TypeError: wrapper() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df['category'] = df['category'].str.split('|').str[0]
```

Outputs:

```
  category  qty
1      abc   23
2      dfs   43
3      fds   34
4      qwe   34
5      fds   21
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
df["category"]=df["category"].str.replace(r"[|].*", "")
```

This will replace the first encountered pipe `|` and everything that is followed by an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by using `apply` and a `lambda` function -

```
df['category'] = df['category'].apply(lambda x: x.split("|")[0])
```

This will split the strings in the category column on every `|` and only return the first part.